# XAML simplify row definitions in Grid

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a lot of (actually all) `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` in my XAML for a single grid. Is there a way to simplify this to declare a grid whose rows have `*` as height?

**EDIT**: Originally ask as `Auto` instead of `*` but the spirit of the question is the same: to simplify repetitive row definitions.

Comment: I think if you just say `<RowDefinition />` it defaults to `Auto`. I could be wrong.

Comment: If they're all just `Auto` anyway, why even bother with the Grid and just throw it all in a single StackPanel?

Comment: @ChrisW. Sorry I meant `*`, not `Auto`.

Comment: @ChrisW. I also want to use `Grid` to take up the entire space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good blog post by Toni Petrina about shorter way of writing Grid row and column definitions.

It comes down to writing it like this:

```
<Grid a:GridEx.RowCol="*,*|*,*">
```

Read more here: [Shorter way of writing Grid row and column definitions](http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/shorter-way-grid-definitions/)

Answer (score 0):

Grid doesn't support control templates (info taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/731bf94e-0881-49e1-a35a-99a2e2ca647f/how-to-put-gridcolumndefinitions-in-style?forum=wpf).).